# getting 500 error messages in nginx site

Tags: nginx

I am running multiple drupal sites on my local dev machine.

This is my current config
http://pastebin.com/jpivzA4m

so when I go to localhost/drupal_test/ one of my drupal sites works well
however when I got to localhost/pw this is another site of mine the front page comes
up but no inner pages I get 500 internal server error.

My friend uses the below config and it works for him. I would like to know
why this is happening. I am new to nginx so I am lost.

http://pastebin.com/dUZbAM0b

error log:

```
2013/11/08 04:17:26 [warn] 7825#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80,   
ignored

2013/11/08 04:17:26 [warn] 7826#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, 
ignored

2013/11/08 04:18:30 [error] 7828#0: *8 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while 
internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: 
"GET /pw/home HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/pw/"
```

Comment: Like with all (500) errors: have you checked the error log?

Comment: I have added it above

Answer (score 0):

In the nginx config you are listening on a unix socket port `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` in the comment you state that the fastcgi server is listening on `127.0.0.1:9000`.
So I would change

`fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;`

to

`fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;`

Comment: it did not help infact even my other sites went down

Comment: according to your nginx config, you only have only site, are you talking about directories? If so then it is NOT site wide as you stated, it is then one of your internal files and thusly not yet nginx config.

Comment: each folder in /sites is a site in itself one of the folders which is pw has a site wide problem. other sites work